# Run shortcode in custom script in wp_head if post type is CPT 'Jobs'

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, shortcode, json, wp-head

i am using genesis framework and types plugin. i create post meta fields for a custom post type name 'jobs' 
[image: post meta fields for jobs CPT]

i want to run a custom javascript named jobpostingschema.js in wp_head if post type is jobs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it in a shortcode, you should enqueue this particular JavaScript file only for the page you want. Place something like this in your `functions.php`:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    if( is_singular('job') ){
      wp_enqueue_script('jobpostingschema', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jobpostingschema.js', array(), '', false);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts');
```

Comment: How can I add this script files to the very top in the wp_head?

Comment: With the above function. You can add an extra 'priority' parameter to `add_action`, for instance  `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts', 10)`, to determine the order in which it is added to the header.